# Don't use 'BuildContext's across async gaps in android studio using flutter

Tags: android, flutter, firebase, dart

**I'm developing a login page on flutter using Firebase and I can't display the popups for wrong email/password, What am i doing wrong? I've read and watch many videos and answers here but it seems i can't find a proper solution for my problem if anyone could help me i would appreciate it. If someone can show me what am i doing wrong i ve uploaded 2 slides of my code**

[slide1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cyr6h.png)
[slide2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PJHLK.png)

Comment: Does this help? https://dart.dev/tools/linter-rules/use_build_context_synchronously

Comment: Not really if you see my screenshots i need this pop on firebase auth and its kinda tricky as to what i have to do

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, please add the code as text in the editor area of the post. Here how to do question in stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass BuildContext on button press.

```
ElevatedButton(onPressed: () => signInUser(context), child: Text('Sign In'));
```

Method code

```
void signInUser(BuildContext context) { //get BuildContext
    showDialog(
      context: context, // use here
      builder: (context) => Center(
        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
      ),
    );

    //same as other dialogs
    showDialog(
      context: context, // use here
      builder: (context) => Center(
        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
      ),
    );
    // call your other dialog like this
     wrongEmail(context);
  }




void wrongEmail(BuildContext context) {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
        title: Text('Error'),
        content: Text('Wrong Email'),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Future.delayed(
                Duration.zero,
                () {
                  ///add code of show dialog here....
                },
              );
```

You can use `Future.delayed` like this.

Answer (score 0):

Problem seems in your first slide, you are directly showing loading dialog from async gap. try moving our showLoading also in seperate method. This will fix the warning. For example

```
  void login() async {
    showLoading();
    try{
      final response = await firbaseLogin()
      hideLoading()
      showSuccess()
    } catch(e){
      hideLoading()
      showError()
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my exact code at the moment.

```html
class LoginPage extends StatefulWidget {
  LoginPage({super.key});

  @override
  State<LoginPage> createState() => _LoginPageState();
}

class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {

  //text editing controllers
  final emailController = TextEditingController();
  final passwordController = TextEditingController();

  //sing user in method
  void signUserIn() async {


    //show loading
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) {
        return const Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        );
      },
    );

    try{
      await FirebaseAuth
          .instance
          .signInWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: emailController.text,
          password: passwordController.text
      );
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      //wrong email
      if (e.code == 'user-not-found') {
        wrongEmailMessage();
      }
      //wrong password
      else if (e.code == 'wrong-password') {
        wrongPasswordMessage();
      }
    }
    //pop the loading circle
    Navigator.pop(context);
  }

  //wrong email message popup
  void wrongEmailMessage() {
    showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) {
          return const AlertDialog(
            title: Text('Incorrect Email'),
          );
        },
    );
  }
  //wrong password message popup
  void wrongPasswordMessage() {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) {
        return const AlertDialog(
          title: Text('Incorrect Email'),
        );
      },
    );
  }
```